# How do I expand all files and folders in Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

There's a button to collapse all, and I use it often.  Sometimes, rarely, I want to expand everything, but there's no button for that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and type * on the numeric keypad.

This also works for projects or even just folders inside a project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You have to use * on the numeric keypad.

Comment: @Scott Thanks Scott. I was hitting shift+8 for a while there so I've added your essential note to the answer.